# libgdx sendHttpRequest from android activity

Tags: android, http, libgdx

I created a simple game with the *libgdx* engine. I have a problem connecting to the server. If I make a request without the android part of my game, everything is all right. But when I try to connect from some activity, my request stops and does not enter to this method:

```
Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new Net.HttpResponseListener() {...}
```

If I try making a call in `MainActivity`, everything works fine. In other games with same code, everything works fine too. How can I properly connect?

Answer (score 0):

Gdx.xxx fields will only work in the activity that Libgdx was initialized with, **MainActivity**.